# Problem in fetching route parameters using route.snapshot

Tags: angular

I have a route with dynamic path segment

```
const route:Routes=[
{path:'customers',component:CustomerComponent}
{path:'customers/:id',component:CustomerComponent}
]
```

So in my customer component im fetching this using 
id:number;

```
constructor(private route:ActivatedRoute){}

ngOnInit(){

this.id= this.route.snapshot.params['id'];

console.log("Id is :",this.id)
}
```

So is console logs "Id is :1" when i go this route path from another component  or it works properly when go this route for the first time "localhost:4200/customers/1" But the problem occurs. I have written a link in 
customers.html file

```
<a [routerLink]="['/customer',2]">loadID2</a>
```

When click this link the url changes to "localhost:4200/customers/2" but the console log is not working it is not showing "Id is :2" no console log is there. 
My problem why is this happening?, the url has changed already but the ngOninit is not working. Can you please help me to solve this problem

Comment: try with ParamMap https://angular.io/api/router/ParamMap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the `ActivatedRoute.snapshot` to get the route params, subscribe to the `ActivatedRoute.paramMap` Observable to get new `id`:

```
this.route.paramMap.subscribe((params : ParamMap)=> {  
      this.id = +params.get('id');
      console.log("Id is :", this.id);        
});
```

Comment: it should be  params=>{this.id=+params.get('id');  }); bacause id is number , but the  console.log("Id is :", this.id);     is still not working  but when bind "id"  to <p>id is : {{id}}</p> it is changing properly. My problem is why the console log is not working, is it angular is not runnig ngOnint when route is same or what is happening in their.

Comment: I think you are trying to `console.log` outside of the `subscribe` call. Since the `paramMap`is an Observable you would only see the changed value inside the `subscribe` callback. Inside the `subscribe` callback you are actually implementing an *Observer*  which has its `next` method called when a new value is received. So if you put the `console.log` in the `ngOnInit` instead of putting inside the subscribe call you won't see the new value as it is changed.

Comment: Yeah you are correct we have to put it inside the subscribe. But i have question that why angular ngOnint is not running when we change route path, Now my code is working properly thanks for that.

Comment: `ngOnInit` is invoked only once, when the component has undergone the change detection for the first time, so you would see the `console.log` output only once. But if you add a `console.log` inside the subscribe call, when the next element is received by the Observer, your implemented the the `next` method will be called and also your `console.log` will be invoked (as you had added it in the implementation of the `next` method in the `subscribe` callback).